# Execute Page_Load on MAIN.aspx after/while returning from a CHILD (windowed) aspx page

Tags: c#, asp.net

Although, I am certified, this is my first real program, so please bear with my novice questions. I checked this, and other forums, for an answer and didn't find any.

I have a MAIN.aspx, from where I launch a windowed aspx page using:

```
    ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(typeof(Page), "", 
    "<script type='text/javascript'>window.open        
    ('CHILD.aspx','','width=800,height=400,toolbar=no,location=no,
    directories=no,status=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=yes,
    resizeable=no,copyhistory=no');</script>", false);
```

This child aspx page displays a gridview with a list of entries that can be selected using a "`Select`" button. On selecting one, user can click on an exit button, to return to the `MAIN. aspx`. The return is performed with these two lines of code:

```
    protected void btnExit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // this line allows the capture of selected values 
        gvSelection_SelectedIndexChanged(sender, e); 
        ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(typeof(Page), "", "window.close()", true);
    }
```

So, far I have been able to verify that on returning to `MAIN.aspx` the values that I saved are usable, `EXCEPT...` `Page_Load` won't execute for obvious reasons.

I need help on how to `EXECUTE` MA`IN.ASPX`("`Page_Load`") while exiting from the windowed ASPX page.

Comment: Sounds like you need to create a post-back on main.aspx somehow. When you change something on CHILD.aspx how are you passing the values to main.aspx?

Comment: I am using Cache to pass parameters between MAIN and CHILD, both ways...

Comment: I did some additional research on my issue, and found that after I click on EXIT, the windowed ASPX page closes. Then, if I attempt to refresh the MAIN ASPX page, it launches the windowed ASPX page, but on closing the window, the MAIN ASPX page has the values populated as expected. 

It seems I am missing code, either in ASPX or ASPX.CS that will fire Page_Load on MAIN ASPX

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could update your code as below:

```
protected void btnExit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // this line allows the capture of selected values 
        gvSelection_SelectedIndexChanged(sender, e); 
        ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(typeof(Page), "", "window.close();window.opener.location.reload();", true);
    }
```